# How can I improve my android layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

So I have made an android layout, it quite simple which consists of `imageView` and few `editText` and `TextView`. When I run my app in real device, the design look different with the one in Android Studio. I did read the [Supporting Different Screen Sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html) and understand that we strongly recommend to use `wrap_content` and `match_parent`.

My problem is how can I improve this layout as the screen looked different in others device by using `wrap_content` and `match_parent` . Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
        android:background="@color/darkpurple"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00aaaaaa"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:text="Save"
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:background="@color/darkpurple"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ImageView
        android:background="@color/light_gray"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="175dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:textColor="#295186"
        android:src="@drawable/camera"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/Date"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Date"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_marginTop="230dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/deep_sky_blue"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:hint="Date"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="265dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/Amount"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Amount"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="310dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:textColor="@color/deep_sky_blue"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:hint="Amount"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:id="@+id/line1"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="345dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="370dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/Comments"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Comments"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="410dp"
        android:paddingBottom="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="13dp"
        android:id="@+id/comments"
        android:textColor="@color/deep_sky_blue"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedcorner_edittext"
        android:hint="Comments"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

ScreenShot of my device. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Android Studio screenshot

[image]

Comment: You should make dimen.xml for multiple screen at least 5. and get dimen from that instead of hardcode.

Comment: Use wrap_content for your ImageView layout_height and layout_width.

Comment: try to use layout_weight property of linear layout, it will provide screen ratio based functionality

Comment: share the screenshot of your emulator/preview

Comment: @SadiqMdAsif edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use layout_below to place a view under a view.here you used marginTop to place all views (this is not right way)it place view  with respect to Parent layout.it will break if height varies.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
    android:background="@color/darkpurple"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <Button
        android:text="Save"
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:background="@color/darkpurple"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<ImageView
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@color/light_gray"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textColor="#295186"
    android:src="@drawable/camera"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/red"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/Date"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="Date"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Date"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageview"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/deep_sky_blue"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:hint="Date"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:id="@+id/line"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/date"
    android:background="#c0c0c0"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/line"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/red"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/Amount"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="Amount"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/Amount"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/amount"
    android:textColor="@color/deep_sky_blue"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:hint="Amount"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:id="@+id/line1"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/amount"
    android:background="#c0c0c0"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/line1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/Comments"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="Comments"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Comments"
    android:paddingBottom="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="13dp"
    android:id="@+id/comments"
    android:textColor="@color/deep_sky_blue"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/roundedcorner_edittext"
    android:hint="Comments"/>
```

Comment: will this support multiple screen ?

Comment: I want to move my ImageView to left hand side.  `android:layout_marginRight="25dp"` recommended to use ?

Comment: How can I move down the comments editText? I quite near to the textView

Answer (score 0):

You have used

```
android:layout_marginTop
android:layout_marginLeft
android:paddingBottom
android:paddingLeft
```

etc. with hardcoded values.

That's where the problem is. The values you have provided may work well on YOUR device but not on others because various devices have various screen resolutions and pixel densities.

For example, on a high density screen 190dp may be too small, while on a low density screen 190dp may be too much.

Therefore, you should use multiple dimens.xml files for supporting different types of screens. You should provide the margin and padding values in those files. At runtime, your app will choose which dimensions to use depending upon the screen type.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in the preview theme.

Change your `Android Studio` designer page preview Theme from `NoTitle` to `NoActionBar` which is your AppTheme.  Select `AppTheme` from the theme selection in the designer preview.

Answer (score 0):

change your app theme to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

this will remove your default action bar. Now you can add your own toolbar and set it as the action bar by

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```